# Simple file upload with multi form controls in ASP

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic

Actually i want to develop one ASP form in which there will be one File Upload Control and another will be few form elements like Text, TextArea, Checkbox, RadioButton. I need to put validation on these controls using Javascript (Client Side) and ASP (Server Side) too.

I had gone through various sites but got only simple file upload without any form element in it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: So you need two separate forms? Are you just looking for help with adding validation?

Comment: No i actually looking help for file upload and Multiple form fields. If its in two separate forms then also not an issue with me. I want that while click on submit all forms value should get in Request and also file should get uploaded at same time if all fields are valid. I dont want two different submit.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a javascript function to validate at client side and pass the form object to it. something like onsubmit="return validate(this)" in the form tag and do all your validations there.

On Server side you have all your submitted data which you can validate as normal. If you are using ASp, it is better to use any third party file uploader object for uploading files as they are easier and safer to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished working on an AJAX file uploader. http://www.plupload.com/example_all_runtimes.php was a good option. If you look at the custom example, you can not only do ajax uploads, but you can attach parameters to the AJAX post, which is what I did. I had a number of form fields on the page, and when the send button was hit, I just had Javascript grab the values of those fields, append them to the post request of the uploader, then I handled them on the server side like any other post. It was a lot of research to find the solution, but it works amazing!